# How can I calculate confidence intervals and determine statistical significance for each cell in a contigency table?

Tags: confidence-interval, categorical-data, contingency-tables

I'm creating a large contigency table to summarise the difference between a bunch of (categorical) demographics across groups.  I would like to know what the confidence intervals are for each cell in the proportional cross-tab, and if the proportion of each demographic group in each sample is statistical different from random. Say I have the following data:

```
> set.seed(1)
> y <- sample(factor(c("Outcome 1", "Outcome 2", "Outcome 3", "Outcome 4")), 1000, replace = T)
> x1 <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 1000, replace=T)
> x2 <- sample(c("Employed full-time", "Employed part-time", "Not in labour force", NA), 1000, replace=T)
> 
> table(x1, y)
        y
x1       Outcome 1 Outcome 2 Outcome 3 Outcome 4
  Female       123       126       124       108
  Male         121       150       108       140
> round(prop.table(table(x1, y), 2) * 100, 1)
        y
x1       Outcome 1 Outcome 2 Outcome 3 Outcome 4
  Female      50.4      45.7      53.4      43.5
  Male        49.6      54.3      46.6      56.5
> 
> table(x2, y)
                     y
x2                    Outcome 1 Outcome 2 Outcome 3 Outcome 4
  Employed full-time         57        64        65        77
  Employed part-time         66        80        57        53
  Not in labour force        57        61        51        58
> round(prop.table(table(x2, y), 2) * 100, 1)
                     y
x2                    Outcome 1 Outcome 2 Outcome 3 Outcome 4
  Employed full-time       31.7      31.2      37.6      41.0
  Employed part-time       36.7      39.0      32.9      28.2
  Not in labour force      31.7      29.8      29.5      30.9
```

How would I compute such a table in R?  I have read papers where Fisher's exact test is used for this purpose, but it seems to me only to be useful for 2 x 2 tables.

Comment: When you say every possible comparison do you really mean comparing outcome2:male with outcome3:female?  Does it also involve comparisons across the tables?

Comment: Possibly what you want is pairwise.t.test or pairwise.wilcoxon.test?

Comment: @John I want to know if each cell (e.g. outcome 1, male) is of different proportion than the whole the sample (e.g. outcomes 1-4, male).

Comment: @John Doucette I have categorical variables only so a t-test or a wilcoxon test which compares differences between means doesn't make sense does it?

Comment: Fisher [works on general tables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FishersExactTest.html); it's not limited to 2 x 2.

Comment: Why not bootstrap the confidence intervals?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed Bonferroni needs to be invoked. Many years ago we proved that it provides a tight upper bound and proposed the M-Test. see:

Fuchs, C. and Kenett, R.S. (1980).  *A Test for Detecting Outlying Cells in the Multinomial Distribution and Two-Way Contingency Tables,* Journal of the American Statistical Association, **75**, pp. 395-398.

Kenett R.S. (1991). *Two Methods for Comparing Pareto Charts,* Journal of Quality Technology, **23**, pp. 27-31.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I could produce to my question was to calculate binomial confidence intervals, and test 2x2 binomial contigency tables for each cell.  I'd appreciate any improvement on this answer:

The function:

```
prop.table.with.cis <- function(x, conf.lev = 0.95, do.fisher.2x2.test = TRUE, compare.to.entire.sample = TRUE, digits = 1, p.digits = 3){
  require(PropCIs)
  t <- addmargins(x, 2)
  prop.t <- prop.table(t, 2)
  prop.t.cis <- prop.t
  for(i in 1:dim(t)[2]){
    ms <- margin.table(t, 2)
    ms.col <- margin.table(t, 1)
    for (j in 1:dim(t)[1]){
       ci <- addz2ci(t[j,i], ms[i], conf.lev)
       names(ci) <- NULL       
       prop.str <- paste(formatC(prop.t[j, i] * 100, digits = digits, format="f"), " (", 
                         formatC(ci[1] * 100, digits = digits, format="f"), ", ",
                         formatC(ci[2] * 100, digits = digits, format="f"), ")", sep = "")
       if (do.fisher.2x2.test){
         if (compare.to.entire.sample){
           fisher.matrix <- matrix(c(t[j, i], sum(t[-j, i]), sum(ms.col[j]) / 2, sum(ms.col[-j]) / 2), nrow=2)
         } else {
            fisher.matrix <- matrix(c(t[j, i], sum(t[-j, i]), sum(ms.col[j]) / 2 - t[j, i], sum(ms.col[-j]) / 2 - sum(t[-j, i])), nrow=2)
         }
         fisher.diff.to.rest.sample <- fisher.test(fisher.matrix)
         prop.str <- paste(prop.str, " p=", 
                         formatC(fisher.diff.to.rest.sample$p.value, digits = p.digits, format="f"),
                         sep="")
       }
       prop.t.cis[j,i] <- prop.str

    }
  }
  return(prop.t.cis)
}
```

and some sample output:

```
> set.seed(10)
> y <- sample(factor(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")), 1000, replace = T)
> x <- sample(c("Employed full-time", "Employed part-time", "Not in labour force", NA), 1000, replace=T)
> prop.table.with.cis(table(x, y))
                     y
x                     Group 1                   Group 2                   Group 3                   Sum                      
  Employed full-time  30.7 (25.3, 36.8) p=0.390 33.7 (28.1, 39.9) p=1.000 36.8 (31.3, 42.6) p=0.414 33.9 (30.6, 37.3) p=1.000
  Employed part-time  36.1 (30.3, 42.3) p=0.438 32.5 (26.9, 38.6) p=0.876 31.6 (26.4, 37.4) p=0.652 33.3 (30.1, 36.8) p=1.000
  Not in labour force 33.2 (27.6, 39.3) p=0.938 33.7 (28.1, 39.9) p=0.814 31.6 (26.4, 37.4) p=0.763 32.8 (29.6, 36.2) p=1.000
>
```

Comment: What does it tell you, or in other words what are your conclusions about those results? (I'm still having trouble with understanding your original question.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you need to consider a Bonferroni type of approach.

You want the probability that there's no error overall

P(error)= 1- P(No Error)

Alpha = 1-(1-Alpha)

Now, we're looking at an overall case.. So I'll call that alphaoverall and alphacell is the chances of making an error in any particular cell..

alphaoverall = 1-(1-alphacell)^n

Now, if you want to get z score in terms of an overall alpha..

alphaoverall = 1-(1-alphacell)^n

alphaoverall -1= -(1-alphacell)^n

1-alphaoverall = (1-alphacell)^n

take the nth root

(1-alphaoverall)^(1/n)= 1- alphacell

(1-alphaoverall)^(1/n)-1= - alphacell

1-(1-alphaoverall)^(1/n)=  alphacell

So, what this means, is say you want a 20% error rate for the whole table, plug in .2 for alpha over all, with your number of cell entries as n.. Say you have a 2*3 table, then that's n= 6.

1-(1-.2)^(1/6) =  0.03650752
 ..

You'll have a 2 sided test, so..

Now, cut that .0365 in 2 ,  0.01825376  now find the score that has that much area in the upper tail, and find the appropriate z is 2.09.

My hunch though, is that the errors in each cell might be correlated. Which I think will matter.. If you don't have an error in one cell, it makes it less likely to have an error in the next cell. Doesn't it?  Come to think of it, if you have a 2x2 table, and one point estimate is very close to the true parameter, the others would have to be very close as well..

Comment: You have a point, but detail is needed for this to become a clear and adequate answer.

Comment: Any thought on @whuber's comment?

Comment: Tough but fair. :) At the same time, my answer wasn't rubbish, so I'm not sure what you want me to say.

Comment: @Adam Agreed. Your response was on the point but we generally expect standalone and justified responses rather than a one-line thought. As another response pointing toward Bonferroni correction has been proposed in the meantime, maybe you could expand a little bit on why we must account for inflation in Type I error rate when analyzing two-way tables at the cell level, or if there's another alternative to Bonferroni correction (which is known to be conservative) that might be suited to this particular case, etc.

Comment: @chl    I edited my response. I'm not sure what to think about it though. Maybe someone can add to it and we can get to the right answer if it's wrong